# Issue with Sessions and Arrays PHP

Tags: php, arrays, session

I did a code that adds the item id to buy in session, but doesn't work as needed, here is the code.

```
    $my_array=array($_SESSION['buyid']);
    array_push($my_array, $id);
    // put the array in a session variable
    $_SESSION['buyid'] = $my_array;
```

but printing the $_session variable in this way:

```
$orderamount = $_SESSION['amount'];
            for ($i=1;$i<$orderamount;$i++){
                $order = $_SESSION[$i]['buyid'];
                print "<pre>";
print_r($_SESSION[$i]['buyid']);
print "</pre>";
```

Outputs this:

```
            Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [0] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [0] => 
                                                                [1] => 14
                                                            )

                                                        [1] => 15
                                                    )

                                                [1] => 7
                                            )

                                        [1] => 8
                                    )

                                [1] => 9
                            )

                        [1] => 10
                    )

                [1] => 11
            )

            Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [0] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [0] => 
                                                                [1] => 14
                                                            )

                                                        [1] => 15
                                                    )

                                                [1] => 7
                                            )

                                        [1] => 8
                                    )

                                [1] => 9
                            )

                        [1] => 10
                    )

                [1] => 11
            )

            Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [0] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [0] => 
                                                                [1] => 14
                                                            )

                                                        [1] => 15
                                                    )

                                                [1] => 7
                                            )

                                        [1] => 8
                                    )

                                [1] => 9
                            )

                        [1] => 10
                    )

                [1] => 11
            )

            Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [0] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [0] => 
                                                                [1] => 14
                                                            )

                                                        [1] => 15
                                                    )

                                                [1] => 7
                                            )

                                        [1] => 8
                                    )

                                [1] => 9
                            )

                        [1] => 10
                    )

                [1] => 11
            )

            Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [0] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [0] => 
                                                                [1] => 14
                                                            )

                                                        [1] => 15
                                                    )

                                                [1] => 7
                                            )

                                        [1] => 8
                                    )

                                [1] => 9
                            )

                        [1] => 10
                    )

                [1] => 11
            )

            Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [0] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [0] => 
                                                                [1] => 14
                                                            )

                                                        [1] => 15
                                                    )

                                                [1] => 7
                                            )

                                        [1] => 8
                                    )

                                [1] => 9
                            )

                        [1] => 10
                    )

                [1] => 11
            )

            Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [0] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [0] => 
                                                                [1] => 14
                                                            )

                                                        [1] => 15
                                                    )

                                                [1] => 7
                                            )

                                        [1] => 8
                                    )

                                [1] => 9
                            )

                        [1] => 10
                    )

                [1] => 11
            )

            Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [0] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [0] => 
                                                                [1] => 14
                                                            )

                                                        [1] => 15
                                                    )

                                                [1] => 7
                                            )

                                        [1] => 8
                                    )

                                [1] => 9
                            )

                        [1] => 10
                    )

                [1] => 11
            )

            Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [0] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [0] => 
                                                                [1] => 14
                                                            )

                                                        [1] => 15
                                                    )

                                                [1] => 7
                                            )

                                        [1] => 8
                                    )

                                [1] => 9
                            )

                        [1] => 10
                    )

                [1] => 11
            )

            Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [0] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [0] => 
                                                                [1] => 14
                                                            )

                                                        [1] => 15
                                                    )

                                                [1] => 7
                                            )

                                        [1] => 8
                                    )

                                [1] => 9
                            )

                        [1] => 10
                    )

                [1] => 11
            )

            Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [0] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [0] => 
                                                                [1] => 14
                                                            )

                                                        [1] => 15
                                                    )

                                                [1] => 7
                                            )

                                        [1] => 8
                                    )

                                [1] => 9
                            )

                        [1] => 10
                    )

                [1] => 11
            )
```

I think there is something wrong, I need to know in a normal array in order to make checkout page, insert data into mysql and do math calculations and other checks but I can't manage to pick variables from the array.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `$_SESSION[$i]` although $_SESSION acts like normal array it's not good idea to iterate over it with for using int keys.

I assume that you want to add buyer id to the session so the code should be as following:

```
// create buyId if it doesn't exist the better name would be "customersIds"
if (!is_array($_SESSION['buyid'])) {
  $_SESSION['buyid'] = [];
}
// assuming that $id is passed somehow to this script when it's not empty add it to array, acts like array_push()
if (!empty($id)) {
    $_SESSION['buyid'][] = $id;
}
```

it will add to the $_SESSION under key 'buyId' next ids. If you want them to be unique you can check before adding with in_array() if the id already exist.

Then if you want to get all the buyers ids from the session.

```
// iterate over array in session and display buyIds
foreach ($_SESSION['buyid'] as $buyId) {
     echo $buyId;
}
```

Comment: doesn't work, It doesn't output anything in the second page when outputting and computing needed